# Is there a way to view the history of edited comments?

Tags: support, comments, review-history

A comment has been changed. I'm interested in viewing a past version of the comment.

Is there a way to view the history of edited comments?

Comment: Good find Ken. I went through the list of suggested related posts, and that one was not there. I'll cast the first close vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### No, there is no way of seeing a comments' history.

Comments are only second class citizens and you can't see revisions of comments, nor undelete them or downvote them...